# Etymology of "Japlac"

Tags: etymology

What's the etymology of the brand name "Japlac"? Is it based on the word "Jap" plus a contraction of lacquer? Or is it a reference to [Japanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanning)?

Onelook doesn't have a reference to the brand name.

Comment: It's a *trade name*. How do we know *exactly* what went through the mind of whoever dreamed it up? Doubtless he was aware of [Japan black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_black), which *can also be called **japan lacquer** and **Brunswick black***.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that "lac" suggested an Indian word, making the trade name sound less related to "Japan" soon after WWII when tensions among states were still well alive:

> - This ***[ad](http://phil-are-go.blogspot.it/2011/11/japlac-what-duck.html)***  is from 1951, when, (you would think) there was still a bit of a sore spot in England when it came to Japan. Although, maybe Americans had more of a problem with the Japanese, due to the whole Pearl Harbor thing. England probably liked the Germans less than they did the Japanese. Still, double-you double-you eye-eye was only six years past when this ad ran. ***It's a bit of an eye-opener to see "jap-anything" sold commercially so soon after "the icky bit" between nations.*** 
>     [image]
> - So, what's the deal with Japlac? Well, when you think about it, it makes some sense. ***The word "lac" can be traced back to an insect which was so numerous in India and China that is was given the name "lac", which was the root of the word "laksha", meaning "one hundred thousand". Lac bugs contained a resin that could be used to make the shiny painty stuff called "lacquer"***.  Ta-da.

(phil-are-go.blogspot.it)

Comment: I've found other adverts from 1949, but nothing earlier than that.
https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-original-advertisement-in-1940s-era-magazine-advertising-japlac-enamel-43410853.html and http://www.advertisingarchives.co.uk/detail/10290/1/Magazine-Advert/Japlac-Paint/1940s

Comment: But, then I found 1943 photo with a tin of Japlac, so I'd suspect it might be a pre-war invention: https://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/205398538